# Bash : Detection of longest match broken by brackets

Tags: string, bash

I'm pretty abismal in bash script and I am trying to detect the index of a substring inside a string and return -1 is said substring is not found

I used the following code to detect the index of 'Disc 1' in a given uaeName string:

```
strindex() { 
   x="${1%%$2*}"
   [[ $x = $1 ]] && echo -1 || echo ${#x}
}

index=`strindex "$uaeName" "Disk 1"`
echo "Disk 1 $index"
```

The problem appears when "Disk 1" is not present in uaeName and uaeName contains brackets.

It works well when said string $uaeName is

```
HydroZone v1.0.0 (1994)(Skull Army)(SW).adf
Disk 1 -1
```

But as soon as $uaeName contains brackets it just fails :

```
HydroZone v1.0.0 (1994)(Skull Army)(SW)[Blitz BASIC].adf
Disk 1 56
```

Somehow the brackets [] inside uaeName seems to be misinterpreted, how can I correct the problem ?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Can you provide a minimal,verifiable input and expected output? Your input string doesn't have `Disk 1` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote your variables inside the strindex function:

```
   [[ "$x" = "$1" ]] && echo -1 || echo "${#x}"
```

Comment: Thank you, this did it. I'm actually a little ashamed to have not seen that by themselve !! :D

Answer (score 0):

That should be `[[ "$x" = "$1" ]]`.